# Phrase for a view dropdown for showing items that are both missing and ready but with warnings

Tags: terminology, mental-models

**The Setup**
A grid has a status for each line item.  These statuses are, Missing, Ready, Missing W/ Warning, Ready W/ Warning.  A warning is triggered when the last external update to that item was rejected.  This allows the controller to check in on those doing the updates and tell them to resubmit.  Items that are ready w/ warning, use the last good state of the line item (so no re-submission is needed as the replacement may have been submited in error, I don't have context to determine this).  The grids default view therefore will show missing lines and ready w/ warning lines.

**The Question**
What do you call this default view so that the user does not get it confused with the Ready or Missing States.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would **"Items that need attention"**
be suitable?

Comment: So far "Needs Attention" is the best I we have come up with, but something about this isn't sitting perfectly, I think it is the fact that depending on the context (ie. how many days out from the event you are) the missing ones don't really need attention as they are expected to be missing at this point.

Comment: Ended up using "Needs Attention" so marking as the answer pending someone submitting something more brilliant in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use just «with warnings»? It is already in your conceptual model, and users will not get confused with it. If it is not fittable, I'd select from such variants: "Important", "In trouble", "Disordered items" or simply "Difficulties" ("Problems").

Comment: The issue with "With Warnings" is that I am reserving that to only show items that have warnings. So regular missing items would be filtered out.  This provides a "check list" view of items I need to follow up with people to make sure the are aware they need to resubmit.